# Newton method not converging with square root equations

Tags: newton-method

I am applying Newton's method to solve the following nonlinear equation systems $F = 0$:
\begin{equation}
F = \left[\begin{array}{l}
\sqrt{(x_0 - x_4)^2  + (x_1 - x_5)^2}  - 6 \\
\sqrt{(x_0 - x_2)^2  + (x_1 - x_3)^2} - \sqrt{(x_4 - x_6)^2  + (x_5 - x_7)^2} \\
\sqrt{(x_0 - x_2)^2  + (x_1 - x_3)^2} - \sqrt{(x_2 - x_4)^2  + (x_3 - x_5)^2}  \\
\sqrt{(x_0 - x_2)^2  + (x_1 - x_3)^2} - \sqrt{(x_0 - x_6)^2  + (x_1 - x_7)^2} \\
\sqrt{(x_0 - x_4)^2  + (x_1 - x_5)^2} - \sqrt{(x_2 - x_6)^2  + (x_3 - x_7)^2} 
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
The initial point is $x_0 = [-1,1,2,2,-3,2,5,-7]$. Newton method converges very slow and in fact the solution grows very big and the residual is only 1e-6 after 100 iterations. At each Newton iteration, I simply compute the pesudo-inverse of the Jacobian and multiply it with the residual to get the descent direction $\Delta x$, then I do $x:= x - \Delta x$.

However, if I change $F$ to the following by removing the square root (the solution of the modified equations are the same)
\begin{equation}
F = \left[\begin{array}{l}
(x_0 - x_4)^2  + (x_1 - x_5)^2  - 36 \\
(x_0 - x_2)^2  + (x_1 - x_3)^2 - (x_4 - x_6)^2  - (x_5 - x_7)^2 \\
(x_0 - x_2)^2  + (x_1 - x_3)^2 - (x_2 - x_4)^2  - (x_3 - x_5)^2  \\
(x_0 - x_2)^2  + (x_1 - x_3)^2 - (x_0 - x_6)^2  - (x_1 - x_7)^2 \\
(x_0 - x_4)^2  + (x_1 - x_5)^2 - (x_2 - x_6)^2  - (x_3 - x_7)^2 
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
and then apply Newton's method, the solution is very reasonable and the residual is 1e-14 after 14 iterations.

However，I want to solve the first equation system due to some validation issue, for example, suppose $x^2 -y^2 = 0$ is solved very accurately, but $x-y = 0$ may not be very accurate if $x+y$ is very small. Is there any alternative to Newton's method so I can solve the first equation systems very accurately? I have tried Quasi-Newton method an trust region method, none of them worked.

Comment: Would it help if you fix the first three variables to their initial values? The solution set is rotation and translation invariant

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried fixing the first three variables, but it still doen't work

Comment: Ok, then your problem is not only the drift of the center-of-gravity.

Comment: The result of course is one of 4 (?) possible squares, with the first 3 coordinates fixed. I feel that equating the distances enforces a rigid behavior of the solver, while equating squared distances introduces some spring-like effect, so that the solution path is more flexible. If you have to go with the distances, it might help to initially introduce one or more extra dimensions, where the distance configuration might be easier to reach, and then minimize the values in these extra dimensions,, hoping that it pops into an admissible flat configuration.

Comment: @Pew Have you tried using higher precision? My intuition tells me that using the first formulation, it won't be possible to compute the right hand side of the linear system "required accuracy" as iterates converge. (Required accuracy is a constant -but problem dependent- multiple of the convergence tolerance)

Comment: I think I found the reason, it is because this nonlinear system has two classes of solutions, the first one is a square of length 10, the second one is very long flat rectangle, Theoretically the second one shouldn't exist, but in numerical worlds, the solution is approximate since the diagonal is equal to the edge if the rectangle is flat enough. So if we choose a bad initial point, then it converges to the solution of flat rectangle, and it is very long, so the solution is not accurate due to floating point calculation limit